# Vector calculus with applications

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

[image: Catenary problem]

**ANSWER**: How can I use the following example and its solution to answer the above catenary problem? What is $V_0?$ Is it 0 or c ?

Example: Find the radial and transverse acceleration of a particle moving in a plane curve
in Polar coordinates.

[image: vector calculus]

Comment: The equation of the curve is given in intrinsic coordinates, so it would be better to stick to those rather than use polar coordinates

Comment: @DavidQuinn, I computed $v=\frac{ds}{dt} =\frac{c}{\cos^2{\psi}}$ Is that correct? or is it $\rho$ the radius of curvature? The $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=\frac{2\cdot c\cdot \sin{\psi}}{cos^3{\psi}}$ Are these computations correct?

Comment: no you need to use the Chain Rule

Comment: @DavidQuinn, $x=c\cdot \sinh^{-1}{\frac{s}{c}}, y= \sqrt{s^2+c^2}, \frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{d(c\cdot sinh{\frac{X}{c}}}{dt}=\cosh{\frac{X}{c}}$ Plugging this value in $\vec{v}=\frac{ds}{dt}c\cdot(\cos{\psi}\hat{i} + \sin{\psi}\hat{j}) + s\cdot \frac{d\psi}{dt}\cdot c\cdot (-sin{\psi}\hat[i} +\cos{\psi}\hat{j})$ we will get $c\cdot (\cosh{\psi} + \sinh{\psi})= v_0\cdot e^{\psi}$ Is these computations correct?

Comment: @DavidQuinn,Please read $\vec{v}=\frac{ds}{dt}c\cdot(\cos{\psi}\hat{i} + \sin{\psi}\hat{j}) + s\cdot \frac{d\psi}{dt}\cdot c\cdot (-sin{\psi}\hat{i} +\cos{\psi}\hat{j})$

Comment: you don't need vectors or a Cartesian frame of reference or hyperbolic functions. I will post a more detailed answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity is $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$ and is directed along the curve.

The acceleration components are $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ along the curve and $\frac{v^2}{\rho}$ in the direction of the normal, where $\rho$, the radius of curvature is given by $\rho=\frac{ds}{d\psi}$.

The question is effectively saying that these two acceleration components are equal.

So $$s=c\tan\psi\implies \frac{ds}{dt}=c\sec^2\psi\frac{d\psi}{dt}$$

At $\psi=0$, the initial velocity is $v_0$, so $$v_0=c\frac{d\psi}{dt}\implies\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\frac{v_0}{c}$$

The tangential component of acceleration is $$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=2c\sec^2\psi\tan\psi\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2+c\sec^2\psi\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}$$

The normal component of acceleration is $$\frac{v^2}{\rho}=\frac{c^2\sec^4\psi\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2}{c\sec^2\psi}=c\sec^2\psi\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2$$

These components are equal, so setting them equal, cancelling non-zero terms and rearranging gives

$$(2\tan\psi-1)\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}=0$$

Now write $\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\dot{\psi}$, so that $$\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}=\dot{\psi}\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}$$

Substituting this into the equation above,

$$(2\tan\psi-1)\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2+\dot{\psi}\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}=0$$

We can cancel $\dot{\psi}$ since this is not zero:
$$(2\tan\psi-1)\dot{\psi}+\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}=0$$

This is a separable variable differential equation:

$$\int_{\frac{V_0}{c}}^{\dot{\psi}}\frac{1}{\dot{\psi}}d\dot{\psi}=\int_0^{\psi}(1-2\tan\psi)d\psi$$
$$\implies\ln\left(\frac{\dot{\psi}c}{V_0}\right)=\psi-2\ln\sec\psi$$

$$\implies\frac{\dot{\psi}c}{V_0}=e^{\psi}\cos^2\psi$$

So the velocity is given by

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=c\sec^2\psi\dot{\psi}=V_0e^{\psi}$$ as required.

The radial component of acceleration is now found to be
$$c\sec^2\psi\left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{{V_0}^2}{c}e^{2\psi}\cos^2\psi$$

The tangential component is the same, therefore the magnitude of the resultant acceleration is $$\frac{\sqrt{2}{V_0}^2}{c}e^{2\psi}\cos^2\psi$$

Comment: It would be better if you give me complete detailed correct answer showing magnitude of velocity =$V_0e^\psi$ and magnitude of acceleration $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{c}\cdot {V_0}^2e^{2\cdot\psi}\cos^2{\psi}$

Comment: I thought you might like to try it yourself

Comment: How did you compute $\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}=\dot{\psi}\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}$ from the previous step $(2\tan{\psi}-1) \left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}?$  Would you explain?

Comment: How and why did you eliminate **t** in the R.H.S. of  last equation?

Comment: Substitute this expression for $\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}$ into the equation above and solve the differential equation. This expression for the second derivative is from the chain rule, like $a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$

Comment: How did you compute $\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}=\dot{\psi}\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}$ from the previous step $(2\tan{\psi}-1) \left(\frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}?$ Would you explain?

Comment: I haven't! This form of the second derivative is just a standard result. I have not deduced it from the other equation. Just substitute the expression $\dot{\psi}\frac{d\dot{\psi}}{d\psi}$ for $\frac{d^2\psi}{dt^2}$ and solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130377/discussion-between-dhamnekar-winod-and-david-quinn).

Comment: I will post the full solution later

Comment: i have posted the solution

Comment: very correct answer, You are very very extra-ordinarily good in mathematics. Great job, great performance. Thank You.

Comment: you are welcome...